# loop through array chunks php

Tags: php, arrays

I divided an array into chunks. I would like to ask how is it possible to loop in them in order to use every chunk as an array and print their data? Here is my code so far..

```
$chunks = array_chunk($newarray, 5, true);

foreach ($chunks as $index => $chunk) {


}
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific. What do you want to achieve? Don't you just need two nested `foreach` loops? But what is the use of chunking in the first place then? Also, limit your code to the relevant part, all the xml and curl stuff just distracts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$chunks = array_chunk($newarray, 5, true);

for($i=0; $i<count($chunks);$i++){
   for($n=0;$n<count($chunks[$i]);$n++){//or $n=0;$n<5;$n++ in your example
      print_r($chunks[$i][$n]);
   }
}
```

array_chunk is indexing all chunks by default [0-..to array size]

or with foreach

```
foreach ($chunks as $index->$chunk)
  foreach($chunk as $key->$value)
   print_r($index.$key.$value);
```